# Basic error in Paskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I've just started to try and learn Haskell, and I have encountered a problem. I am using windows CMD and I have created a `program.hs` .txt file for my first program, which includes a simple a + b function. I have written `answer = a + b` in the txt file, and then I opened the GHCI in CMD. I loaded my program successfully, but when I typed `answer 1 5` instead of returning 6 it returns

```
Variable not in scope: answer :: Integer -> Integer -> t
```

Please can you help and explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ben and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be very helpful if you added your code to your question. Here's a link that will help you create a StackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you did not load the file correctly. Maybe you loaded another file? It's hard to tell.

"Not in scope" in GHCi means that the module you loaded (if any) does not export that variable.

Further, your Haskell code is wrong. `answer = a + b` assumes that variables `a` and `b` are already defined when you load the module, e.g. they have been defined there. This will trigger a "not in scope" error for those variables.

If you intend `answer` to be a function, then you need to define it as a function, e.g.

```
answer a b = a + b
   --  ^^^  --
```

Note the additional arguments.